# Error when trying to debug log file: Unable to retrieve breakpoint info from language server, language server is not ready

Tags: debugging, debug, debug-logs, apex-debugger, apex-replay-debugger

I receive the following error when trying to debug a log file:

> Unable to retrieve breakpoint info from language server, language
> server is not ready.

I already reloaded my VS Code window, what normally fixes issues with breakpoint errors.
There is little to find about this error in the internet. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit... I think its related to the Apex language server not being activated since a couple of days.

Comment: I have the same problem, maybe because of the new Winter '24 Major Release (August 26), a day before it was working fine

Comment: I have a possible workaround.

Go to the settings of VS Code and search for "salesforcedx-vscode-apex".
Look for the Java: Home entry and paste there the path of your Java jdk.
If you dont have Java installed I recommend to download the newest 17 version.
@Vneq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out myself how to solve this (with the hint of a colleague).

1. Go to the settings of VS Code and search for "salesforcedx-vscode-apex".
2. Look for the Java: Home entry and paste there the path to your Java jdk.
3. If you dont have Java installed I recommend to download the newest 17 version. Use this path, for example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.

Comment: Thanks it works

Comment: This worked for me.  Note that I had a different jdk version and had to install jdk-17 to get my debugging working again.

Comment: Didn't work for me...

Comment: Nb : I posted a topic here, same issue, I still have no answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409961/vsc-error-while-using-sfdx-update-checkpoints-in-org-unable-to-retrieve-bre