# VSC - Error while using SFDX: Update checkpoints in Org - Unable to retrieve breakpoint info from language server, language server is not ready

Tags: checkpoint

**[EDIT 9/7/23 : it's now working, even if I didn' restart VC nor my computer ... Any idea how it decided to work today..]**

I'm doing [Find and Fix Bugs with Apex Replay Debugger's trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/fr/content/learn/projects/find-and-fix-bugs-with-apex-replay-debugger/apex-replay-debugger-debug-your-code?trailmix_creator_id=strailhead&trailmix_slug=prepare-for-your-salesforce-platform-developer-i-credential) that focuses on learning how to debug in VSC.

I'm at that stage where I've to use SFDX:Update Checkpoints in Org
[image]

### I'm facing that error :
[image]

[image]

I read about that same problem [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409650/error-when-trying-to-debug-log-file-unable-to-retrieve-breakpoint-info-from-lan), but the fix doesn't help in my case :
Here is my configuration of Java Home and Path :
[image]
In my Explorer, that's the folder :
[image]

Actually it seems ok because Wind+R and java -version cli gives me :
[image]

I also added in VSC settings the path to jdk 17 :
[image]

I have no more fix ideas, feel free to help ... !

Comment: Hi @Alexis,
Seems like a tough nut this one. I looked into my system variables and I see my JAVA_HOME entry is pointing to something different than the JDK. It's C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-8.0.282.8-hotspot.

Maybe you can try to download this JDK.

Comment: Hey @PieterJacob !
Thanks for your answer,
I already installed Java 17 (I was previsously using v8),
When I CLI-ask for java version :
"echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17"
Isn't it right ?
I've to admit I've to admit it's not the first time I have difficulties with environment variables etc.

Nb : I reinstalled everything on another computer, and validate the challenge. But still, I can't debug using my computer.

Comment: in all honesty, I had not installed the JDK17 at all. But my JAVA_HOME entry was already setup to AdoptOpenJDK. Maybe you can try this one, you can download it at: https://adoptopenjdk.net and set it to your environment variable.

You can also log a case at Salesforce if this doesn't work at help.salesforce.com. I have good experiences with this, in the sense that they respond quickly.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey again,
I'm both happy and disappointed, because I just try again and... It worked. In my computer, changing nothing, not restarting VSC nor the computer.
I can't understand why it didn't work yesterday, but today it's working.
Thanks for your help, anyway, you rock !!

Comment: No problem @Alexis. It might be related to caching. Something to consider if it happens again is to delete file .../.sfdx/tools/.../apex.db.
See more here: https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/language-server

There is mentioned something about this under Reset Apex Indexing

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

In my case, Clearing the Apex Language Server's indexing helped me.

To clear the Apex Language Server’s indexing, delete the following directory and restart VScode:

```
PROJECT_DIR/.sfdx/tools/<Salesforce Release>
```

In my case was this directory:

[image]

You can find more information here:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/language-server#reset-apex-indexing
- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000g8clQAA